# Pipeline permission in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm not good at devops stuff and I'm afraid to mess something up, so:
I need to take away permissions to create and change pipelines in Jenkins to developers, but I don't know which ones they need to work with. I assume it's from the "job" section.

[image]

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.